# org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException?

Tags: hive, apache-superset, pyhive

I have Configured HDP 2.6 in my server ,everything is working fine. Even I am able to connect to superset to hive.

when I am trying to visualise the data finding respective error:

```
(pyhive.exc.OperationalError) TExecuteStatementResp(operationHandle=None status=TStatus(sqlState=08S01 infoMessages=[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error return code 1 from 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask:28:27
org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:324

org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runQuery:SQLOperation.java:199

org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:230

org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:264

org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:479

org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:454  sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41:invoke::-1
```

Comment: i know its been a while, but did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @y2k-shubham yes i found a soultion, you need to allow hive to write for multiple users